# Calculation of business hours between two time

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I would like to write a function that calculate working business hours in python, to do that I don't like to define a class and use python ready function to calculate.

I tried with following code but this is not what I wanted.
do you have any suggestion?

```
import datetime

start_time = datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 1, 22, 45, 25)
end_time = datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 7, 10, 00, 00)

hours = BusinessHours(start_time, end_time, worktiming=[9, 18], weekends=[6, 7], holidayfile=None)
print(hours.gethours())
```

I would like to have an input as of "2019-12-01 09:30:00" and "2019-12-07 12:15:00" and the output should be 40 hours

Comment: Did you try [Timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) ?

Comment: Timedelta is not what I want, I like to write a function for calculation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Business Hours Between Two Dates in Pandas Dataframe (including holidays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899627/business-hours-between-two-dates-in-pandas-dataframe-including-holidays)